# How to determine that class is abstract using Java Mirror API?

Tags: java, apt, annotation-processing, mirroring

I am writing an annotation processor, and want to determine based on   `javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement` that corresponding fields type is an abstract or concrete class. Or it is an interface. 
How to do that?

#### Example

```
@SomeAnnotation
public class SomeClass {
    private Map<String,String> interfaceField;
    private AbstractMap<String,String> abstractField;
    private HashMap<String, String> concreteField;
}
```

So, I have `VariableElement` for each field. And want to know that type of *interfaceField* is an interface, type of *abstractField* is abstract and that type of *concreteField* is concrete class.

If I call `.getModifiers()`, I got *private*. If I call `.getKind()`, I got "FIELD". So, it can't help

Comment: Did you  mean "reflection API" instead of "mirror"?

Comment: No, I mean [Mirror API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/apt/mirror/overview-summary.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Element#getModifiers()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#getModifiers()) will tell you if the `class` is `abstract` or not:

```
    if (element.getModifiers().contains(Modifier.ABSTRACT)) { ... }
```

[Element#getKind()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#getKind()) will tell you if it is an `interface`:

```
    if (element.getKind() == ElementKind.INTERFACE) { ... }
```

---

To get the information from all of a class's fields, you should use a `TypeVisitor`:

```
TypeVisitor<Void, VariableElement> type_visitor = new TV();
for (VariableElement field : ElementFilter.fieldsIn(cls.getEnclosedElements())) {
    field.asType().accept(type_visitor, field);
}
```

Where `type_visitor` is your own customized `TypeVisitor`, which through a variety of hoops, is able to get an `Element` you can call the above `getKind()` and `getModifiers()` methods on:

```
class TV extends SimpleTypeVisitor8<Void, VariableElement> {

    @Override
    public Void visitDeclared(DeclaredType type, VariableElement field) {
        System.out.println(field.getSimpleName());
        System.out.println("  type = " + type.toString());
        System.out.println("  modifiers = " + field.getModifiers());
        Element e = type.asElement();
        System.out.println("    kind = " + e.getKind());
        System.out.println("    modifiers = " + e.getModifiers());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Given the following class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Properties properties;
    private List<String> strings;
    // ...
}
```

I get the following output:

```
properties
  type = java.util.Properties
  modifiers = [private]
    kind = CLASS
    modifiers = [public]
strings
  type = java.util.List<java.lang.String>
  modifiers = [private]
    kind = INTERFACE
    modifiers = [public, abstract]
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not accurately described the issue.
Your answer works well for determining the type when processing the class. But is there any way to determine this information for field type inside the class?

Comment: Sounds like you want `List<VariableElement> fs = ElementFilter.fieldsIn(someClass.getEnclosedElements());`.   You can then examine each `VariableElement` and call `getKind()` and/or `getModifiers()` on those.

Comment: This can't help. Added an example.

Comment: @ViktorShatrov Updated answer with the required intermediate steps to get the `Element` you can call `getKind()` and `getModifiers()` on.